# How do I stop my discord bot form spamming

Tags: python, discord.py

```
@client.command(aliases=['Guess', 'guess'])
async def _Guess(ctx, *, Input):

Hold = 1
start_time = time.time()

input = int(Input)
a = input/2
a = math.floor(a)
b = input + input/2
b = math.floor(b)

gNum = 0


while (Hold == 1):
  guess = randint(a,b)
  await ctx.send(guess)
  await discord.TextChannel.last_message.delete()
  gNum + 1
  await ctx.send(gNum)
  await discord.TextChannel.last_message.delete()
  if (guess == input):
    await ctx.send ("The number you picked was...")
    await ctx.send (guess)
    Hold = Hold +1
    await ctx.send("It took %s seconds to find your number." % (time.time() - start_time))
```

I would like to delete the message that it just sent so it does not spam the chat. How would I do this? I know that this is not the right way to do it ( await discord.TextChannel.last_message.delete()) but u just wanted to place it there as a placeholder.

Comment: Can you please fix your formatting? There seems to be multiple indentation issues, along with the strange `gNum = 0 '''` line that breaks up the two code blocks.

Comment: So sorry I just saw that. One sec

Comment: Sorry about that again. Just fixed it.

Comment: A quick search on google reveals [this](https://www.codegrepper.com/code-examples/python/discord.py+delete+own+message) - it seems that the second example would help the most, but I haven't tried it to see if it works.

Comment: Ya I think I got it thanks!

Comment: The formating is horrendous

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can save the messages which the bot sends.
if you have the message objects you can delete them easily (even with delay if wanted).

your code would look like this:

```py
@client.command(aliases=['Guess', 'guess'])
async def _Guess(ctx, *, Input):

Hold = 1
start_time = time.time()

input = int(Input)
a = input/2
a = math.floor(a)
b = input + input/2
b = math.floor(b)

gNum = 0


while (Hold == 1):
  guess = randint(a,b)
  message = await ctx.send(guess)
  await message.delete()
  gNum + 1
  message = await ctx.send(gNum)
  await message.delete()
  if (guess == input):
    await ctx.send("The number you picked was...")
    await ctx.send(guess)
    Hold = Hold +1
    await ctx.send("It took %s seconds to find your number." % (time.time() - start_time))
```

you can set a delay in the `delete()` attribute with `delay=10` for 10 seconds.
there is a [documentation](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/stable/api.html#discord.Message.delete) too.